# keyboard can't be used directily in Toplevel python

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard, window, toplevel

I'm using `Toplevel` to produce two windows. But when it opens the second window, the keyboard is not activated instantly (both windows are opened at the same time), I need to click the second window first in order to use the keyboard. I tried to use `root.lift` to fix it, but it doesn't work. What is the problem here?

My codes:

```
class practisePage1():
       def __init__(self, master):
           self.master = master
           self.master.update_idletasks()
           self.master.attributes('-fullscreen', True)  
           self.button1 = Button(self.master, text="NEXT", bg='gray77',   command=self.gotoPage3, anchor=CENTER)
           self.button1.pack()   

       def gotoPage1(self):
           self.root1 = Toplevel(self.master)
           self.instPage1 = practisePage1(self.root1)

class practisePage1():
       def __init__(self, master):
           self.master = master
           self.master.update_idletasks()
           self.master.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

           self.choiceA = master.bind('a', self.showResultEx1)  #can't be used directly, the window needs to be clicked first
           self.choiceB = master.bind('l', self.showResultEx2) #can't be used directly.


       def showResultEx1(self):
            #some codes
       def showResultEx2(self):
            #some codes
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried giving the window focus with `focus_set`?

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley! It is a focus problem. It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is keyboard focus problem. I add `focus_set()` before I bind my keyboard, it solves the problem.